# Alterar fundo de botão Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Qual seria a forma correta, de alterar o fundo de um botão no bootstrap 4, para uma cor personalizada:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Buscar</button>
```

para

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="background-color: #BLABLA">Buscar</button>
```

Pensei em adicionar um background-color, no atributo style direto no button, mas será que essa é a forma mais correta?

Answer (score 0):

Crie um arquivo .css com as suas próprias definições e carregue-o após o .css do Bootstrap.

Ficaria assim:

```
<!-- CSS DO BOOTSTRAP -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- CSS PESSOAL -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="seu_css.css">
```

No arquivo `seu_css.css` você coloca:

```
.btn-primary{
   background-color: #BLABLA;
}
```

Isso fará com que TODOS os botões Bootstrap `.btn-primary` fiquem com a cor de fundo `#BLABLA`. Caso não queira alterar a classe `.btn-primary` de forma global, crie uma classe personalizada:

```
.btn-pessoal{
   background-color: #BLABLA;
}
```

E adicione essa classe que você criou no botão:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-pessoal">Buscar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta você olhar o código CSS do [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css) e então verificar o que acontece em cada classe como por exemplo a classe .btn-primary pois dependendo do estado (hover,disabled e etc) do botão ele pode ter cores diferentes.
Após identificar todas as classes você pode simplesmente criar um arquivo com essa mesma classe ou outro nome, só mudando as cores:

```css
.btn-personalizado {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  border-color: red;
}

.btn-personalizado:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: orange;
  border-color: orange;
}

.btn-personalizado:focus,
.btn-personalizado.focus {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: black;
  border-color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(49, 132, 253, 0.5);
}

.btn-personalizado:active,
.btn-personalizado.active,
.show>.btn-personalizado.dropdown-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}

.btn-personalizado:active:focus,
.btn-personalizado.active:focus,
.show>.btn-personalizado.dropdown-toggle:focus {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(49, 132, 253, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- ESTILO PERSONALIZADO -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estiloPersonalizado.css">

<button class="btn btn-primary ">Buscar</button>
<button class="btn btn-personalizado ">Personalizado</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No arquivo css :

```
.btn-primary {
    background-color: #BLABLA;
}
```